# Copying one pointer to another gives a different address in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

I have an odd problem here. I have a NSMutableArray of objects that i am treating as a grid. I simply convert coordinates to the index.

I am moving up Y coordinates and at times need to switch objects.

For example: 1101111 -> 1110111 -> 1111011 -> 1111101 and etc (switching the object represented by 0 up the Y coordinate one by one on each pass in the for loop)

In this loop, when i see i need to move an object down, i am keeping track of where i am going to move it. It may be moving more than one object away.
I have an object pointer pointing to nil, and i loop through objects using a temp pointer. If the criteria matches i assign the temp pointer to the first one. The first time i do this it works fine, after that i get a different address.

```
for (int x = 0; x < nCols; ++x) {

    for (int y = 0; y < nRows; ++y) {
        CGPoint currentCellCoord = ccp(x,y);
        Cell *currentCell = [self activeCellAtCoord:currentCellCoord];
        if (currentCell == nil)
            continue;

        if ([currentCell markedAsMatched]) {
            isEmptySpace = YES;
            continue;
        }
        if ([currentCell canMove] == NO) {
            continue;
        }

        if (isEmptySpace) {
            // We might have a spot below it
            Cell *moveToCell = nil;
            for (NSInteger mtc = y-1; mtc >= 0; --mtc) {
                CGPoint moveToCoord = ccp(x, mtc);
                Cell *tmpGC = [self activeCellAtCoord:moveToCoord];

                if ([tmpGC canMove] == NO)
                    break;

                if ([tmpGC markedAsMatched] == YES) {
                    moveToCell = tmpGC; //Works the first time, after that moveToCell will equal some other value
                }
                else{
                    // End of free space, use last one
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (moveToCell != nil) {
                [self exchangeCell:[currentCell currentCoord] toCoord:[moveToCell currentCoord]
                           animate:YES withDuration:0.5]; //This uses exchangeObjectAtIndex
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This part:

```
                    if ([tmpGC markedAsMatched] == YES) {
                    moveToCell = tmpGC; //Works the first time, after that moveToCell will equal some other value
                }
```

Is where i see the issue, the first time you step through this you'll see something like:

moveTocell (nil) = tmpGC (0xc55ff480)
then step past it and both equal (0xc55ff480) as expected

Now we move up the Y coordinate and the next time i will see

moveTocell (nil) = tmpGC (0xc55ff480)
then step past it and tmpGC equals (0xc55ff480) but moveToCell equals (0xbfff645).

That weird moveToCell address is not the address of any object in my array and i put breakpoints to check for Cell creation and it does not occur.
The object is a Cell but with a lot of missing data.

I know i can rewrite this differently to avoid the pointers but i feel like i need to understand the behavior of why i am getting a totally different address...and not the first time.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried NSLog with %p in the format string to print these addresses in the correct scope?  I worry that looking at these assignments in the debugger can be misleading.

Comment: Don't confuse the pointer memory location with the object the pointer is pointing at.
Insight on the memory locations would depend on how these are being stored, allocated etc.

Comment: I'm a little confused and feel like I must not have followed the narrative correctly. It seems like you *should* be getting different values each time through the loop since the variables are created anew with different values each time.

Comment: I will try the NSLog with %p to make sure when i can in a little while, but the object is wrong anyway. The first time i can see the correct object and the next time on it looks wrong, (blank data all over). And @Chuck, I am not creating anything new. These are all just in an array and being switched into different spots.

Comment: Anything special about the Cell class?  exchangeCell... has a duration and an animation?  Is it complete before you get to the assignment?

Comment: I just tried the %p in the NSLog and it looked fine. It is really odd, the debugger shows the object as having some weird address that does not seem to exist..the data in the object (what i can see in the debugger) is corrupt looking. But if i highlight and print the description then it shows the address as correct. I traced it further and after passing it to the next function everything looks fine. I still see an issue but this was not the cause. My problem must be somewhere else, i will ignore this and use %p next time i want to check the address, i don't trust the debugger now. thanks